# I receive an error log from my program

Tags: java, android

I am new to android programming.
In this code I receive an error log and I don't know what to do. I try different things but I still receive the error log. It is something wrong with the input stream, the buffer is not properly created.

Logs :

```
03-06 21:42:32.897: W/InputEventReceiver(24352): Attempted to finish an input event 
but the input event receiver has already been disposed.    
03-06 21:42:32.906: V/FetchWeatherTask(24352): Built URI 
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7    
03-06 21:46:48.231: E/FetchWeatherTask(24352): Error
```

This is the code :

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

public ForecastFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   forecast
    String[] data = {
            "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
            "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
            "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
            "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
            "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
            "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
            "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
    };
    List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));


    ArrayAdapter<String> forecastAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(), 
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast, 
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, 
                    weekForecast);

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(forecastAdapter);

    return rootView;
}

public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;


        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");


            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

           // I think down in the code is something wrong !!!
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {

                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {

                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {//this is the log that i get
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);

            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should give us a hint by posting that error log you are given ;)

Comment: This are the logs:  03-06 21:42:32.897: W/InputEventReceiver(24352): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
03-06 21:42:32.906: V/FetchWeatherTask(24352): Built URI http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7
03-06 21:42:32.920: E/FetchWeatherTask(24352): Error

Comment: OH no, please edit them into your post using the "edit" button below the tags

Comment: I've sent this question into the "Help and Improvement" queue in review - I think it needs a few more details before it's really answerable.

Comment: InputEventReceiver(24352): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: I think the data is not read properly from the URL

Comment: ArtOfCode, I can give you more details if you ask me !!

Comment: Needs more details, try and narrow the problem down to a few lines of code if possible. Dumping a ton of code and is not really useful, I know you are new but if you have not learnt how to use the debugger at a basic level, learn that and thank me later. It will save you many headaches (and us).

According to my search results,this is not your fault and instead a problem with Android. Does it cause the program to crash or hang? or break its functionality?

Comment: It cause break its functionality. the "forecastJsonStr" string doesn't contain the data from the link: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7

Comment: fyi this is code from the Android Udacity course - solutions can alway be found at https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine/tree/2.01-network-call (or maybe another branch)